# Ways to Match multiple set in a trigger to give an error when match is found

Tags: soql, before-trigger

Ways to Match multiple set in a trigger to give an error when match is found

my below trigger is executing when its finding match with content even its with different account please suggest a way to match the content with its account or with its contact

```java
exsitingAL = [SELECT Id, Contact__c, Account__c, Content_Approved__c FROM Approved_Content__c WHERE Content_Approved__c IN :setContentIds AND (Account__c IN :setOrgIds OR Contact__c IN :setContactIds)];
            
for(Approved_Content__c triggerItem :triggerNew){
    for(Approved_Content__c exsitingLitItem :exsitingAL){
        if(triggerItem.Content_Approved__c == exsitingLitItem.Content_Approved__c && (triggerItem.account__c == exsitingLitItem.account__c || triggerItem.Contact__c == exsitingLitItem.Contact__c)){
            triggerItem.addError('Duplicate records found');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Set` to do this. We create a set based on the existing data, then we can check it in the loop.

```
Set<Approved_Content__c> contents = new Set<Approved_Content__c>();
for(Approved_Content__c existingContent: [SELECT Id, Contact__c, Account__c, Content_Approved__c FROM Approved_Content__c WHERE Content_Approved__c IN :setContentIds AND (Account__c IN :setOrgIds OR Contact__c IN :setContactIds)]) {
  contents.add(new Approved_Content__c(Content_Approved__c=existingContent.Content_Approved__c, Contact__c=existingContent.Contact__c));
  contents.add(new Approved_Content__c(Content_Approved__c=existingContent.Content_Approved__c, Account__c=existingContent.Account__c));
}
for(Approved_Content__c content: Trigger.new) {
  Approved_Content__c contactKey = new Approved_Content__c(Content_Approved__c=existingContent.Content_Approved__c, Contact__c=existingContent.Contact__c);
  Approved_Content__c accountKey = new Approved_Content__c(Content_Approved__c=existingContent.Content_Approved__c, Account__c=existingContent.Account__c);
  if(contents.contains(contactkey) || contents.contains(accountKey)) {
    content.addError('Duplicate records found');
  }
  contents.add(contactKey); 
  contents.add(accountKey);
}
```

You can also use a Map in a similar manner if you want to make sure you don't get false positives when using this as an after insert, after update operation.